# Regex: extracting multiple lines if they have the same ID

Tags: python, string, extract

This is the text (from a Persian corpus):

```
1 Jaryane senID=39968
2 mosum senID=39968
3 be senID=39968
...
12 ast senID=39968

1 Magar senID=39969
2 nemishavad senID=39969
...
10 ؟ senID=39969
```

I want to extract lines starting with anything and ending with "؟" (Persian question mark). Like this:

```
1 Magar senID=39969
2 nemishavad senID=39969
...
10 ؟ senID=39969
```

Is there any way to extract multiple lines with the same ID (senID=...) and end with "؟"?

Comment: Does those `. . .`  means some text?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes. It's a sentence with, for example, 10 words.

Comment: Does "ending with ؟" means that the last line is always a single "؟" plus "sendID###" as in your example?

Comment: That line 10 does not have the same `senID`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Is there a reason for using regex? What about splitting the lines, and collecting the ones with the same ID (maybe a dictionary?, a list?) if the last element has "؟"?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Yes. It ends with a "؟" and a sentID.

Comment: @rici Oh, that was a typo. Sorry! I've edited it.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly You're right. I just wondered if it is possible.

Comment: @Saeid01, try [`^1\b(?:(?!\r?\n\r?\n).)*\u061F.*?$`](https://regex101.com/r/pY2JCi/2). Don't forget [`re.M`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M) and [`re.S`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.S) flags.